# printing reports to paper

Tags: php, html, printing, header, footer

I need to print out some PHP-generated reports to paper. Well, some HTML, a browser and a printer…

The problem comes when the client wants to add a header and a footer in each page of the reports. Sometimes, the content fits in one page. But sometimes it doesn’t, so I’ll need to print the header and footer in each printed page (with some mark as “Page 1 out of 15”, the logo, and details on each report).

How is it with codeigniter and without creating a PDF?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accomplish this without using a PDF library, the most modern way to do this is to create a CSS that is customized for printing out the report.

If you Google "[print CSS](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=print+css)" there are a lot of tutorials/examples to get you started.